# Web Scraping using C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape below url:

https://threatmap.checkpoint.com/ThreatPortal/livemap.html

I am scraping ATTACKS TODAY i.e shown in no as 952,xxx.

I wrote below code in C#

```
  public partial class Form4 : Form
{
    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new MyScript();
    }

    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://threatmap.checkpoint.com/ThreatPortal/livemap.html");
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript: window.external.CallServerSideCode();");
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class MyScript
    {
        public void CallServerSideCode()
        {
            var doc = ((Form4)Application.OpenForms[0]).webBrowser1.Document;
        }
    }
}
```

But it's taking lot of time to get loaded in .NET browser and code seems to get hanged for a lot of time.
Any solution please.

Comment: You need to wait for the complete response to finish. You can use `Thread.Sleep`

Comment: Is there any other way around like api or json file?

Comment: You can use `Http Client` nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you don't even need a headless browser. Just make request with whatever library wraps cURL in your language and make GET request to this datapoint:

```
https://threatmap.checkpoint.com/ThreatPortal/rest/livemap/startup
```

which gives this nice JSON at the time of writing:

> {"topAttackingCountries":["US","NO","TR","CA","DE","BA","CY","NL","FR","SG"],"topTargetCountries":["IN","ID","ES","TW","VN","MX","US","AU","NG","NO"],"todayTotalAttacks":1149415,"yesterdayTotalAttacks":6921731}

Comment: this is what i needed.but can i ask you a question how did you get to this url ?

Comment: I opened DevTools in Chrome, Network panel, loaded the URL and quickly looked through network requests, clicking at some and checking what was in the response. After all of the usual endless Angular stuff came data. This is the usual process of studying a site which you intend to work with.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! 
As you said I tried for url : https://www.spamcop.net/spamgraph.shtml?
But here I can see w3m instead of json or xml .Though I can see the data in preview like "total reported(last 24 hours)".
But how can I extract it in json or xml format .Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need to research **each** site you're going to work with because they're *all different*! For spamcop you'd need to send POST-request to the endpoint you found: `curl -d "action=graphdata&period=spamstats" https://www.spamcop.net/w3m` and it will return JSON with data.

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAgilityPack has some great features for querying the dom of html content.  You just pull the html code down using a WebClient then parse it with HtmlAgilityPack
http://html-agility-pack.net/

Comment: Htmlagility Pack gives you client side HTML content.Bu t here we need server side HTML content

Comment: All of the dom on a page is client side.  You can't access any server side data on a site unless you have access to the server.  Scraping another website is always pulling the client side code.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the number of *ATTACKS TODAY* e.g. **952,xxx** you can use the following *Locator Strategy* :

```
string todayAttacksCount = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='pinkBorder' and @id='AttacksCountContainer']//following-sibling::h3[1]//strong")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

As the *AUT* is *JavaScript* / *Ajax* based you may require to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows :

```
IWebElement todayAttacksCount = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//div[@class='pinkBorder' and @id='AttacksCountContainer']//following-sibling::h3[1]//strong")));
Console.WriteLine(todayAttacksCount.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
```